# GitPython nothing appears in working copy after pull

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I'm new in PythonGit and I have problem with pulling and pushing. I created locally bare repo and pushed to it an initial commit. After that I tried to init new user repo using PythonGit, fetch it and pull from it. I have no problem with initialize the repo however I can't get anything from remote/bare repo. My code:

```
import git

repo = git.Repo.init('.')
origin = repo.create_remote('origin', '/home/paweber/git/my-repo.git')
origin.fetch()            
repo.create_head('master', origin.refs.master).set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master)
origin.pull()
```

In ipython console for fetch and pull I get:

```
In [5]: origin.fetch()
Out[5]: [<git.remote.FetchInfo at 0x7f4a4d6ee630>]
```

for fetch and

```
In [6]: origin.pull()
Out[6]: [<git.remote.FetchInfo at 0x7f4a4d6e6ee8>]
```

for pull. After pull action, nothing is pulled at all and repo is still empty but exists. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I guess empty_repo should be repo, which you initialized with a path. Otherwise it might not know where to store your files.

Comment: Sorry just bug in the example code, now is correct

Comment: I could reproduce your result. Actually, the files are just deleted. You can check out or reset --hard your repository. I do not know why this happens, though I guess it has something to do with the create_head line of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pull()` doesn't do anything as `master` is already at its destination commit, the one pointed to by `origin/master`.

This code will work as expected:

```
import git

repo = git.Repo.init('.')
origin = repo.create_remote('origin', '/home/paweber/git/my-repo.git')
origin.fetch()
# the HEAD ref usually points to master, which is 'yet to be born'            
repo.head.ref.set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master)
origin.pull()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how properly resolve this problem but the only idea is as phobic say to reset hard repo after create_head.

```
import git

repo = git.Repo.init('.')
origin = repo.create_remote('origin', '/home/paweber/git/my-repo.git')
origin.fetch()            
repo.create_head('master', origin.refs.master).set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master)
origin.pull()
repo.head.reset('--hard')
```

After that all further pulls should work properly.