# How can I use gitpython to run 'git pull alias_name master' where alias_name is a custom alias?

Tags: python, git, github, git-pull, gitpython

I am relatively new to Python and am attempting to use GitPython to pull changes down from a remote repository to its local counterpart that has already been cloned.

Outside of the script, running 'git pull alias_name master' (Where alias_name is a custom alias) directly from terminal works every time. I verify that the local repo actually updated by comparing the commit SHA between the local instance of the repo and the remote

```
cd path/to/local/instance/of/repo
git pull alias_name master
git log --pretty=format:'%h' -n 1
```

If what is returned above matches the commit SHA for the web interface for the remote repo, I know the local repo has pulled down the latest changes.  Each time I run this from terminal, the SHAs match up and I can see the debugger pull down the latest changes.

When running the following, the script executes without any errors being thrown, but the local repo is not updated because the SHAs do not match up after running the script.

Here is what I have:

```
import git
from git import Repo

repo= git.Repo(path/to/local/instance/of/repo)
o = repo.remotes.origin
repo.heads.master.set_tracking_branch(o.refs.master)
repo.heads.master.checkout()
o.pull()
o.push()
```

I essentially am wondering if there any way to tell gitpython to run 'git pull alias_name master' instead of  'git pull -v origin' (which it appears to be running by default with o.pull())?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[GitPython nothing appears in working copy after pull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272383/6309)", if you set `master` already at `origin/master`, the pull might not do much..

Try in your case a fetch first.

```
o.fetch()
repo.head.ref.set_tracking_branch(o.refs.master)
o.pull()
```

Or, as shown in the [official tutorial](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#handling-remotes), make sure a local master does exist, create it if not:

```
empty_repo.create_head('master', origin.refs.master).set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master).checkout()
```

Comment: Running `empty_repo.create_head('master', origin.refs.master).set_tracking_branch(origin.refs.master)` 

produces an error:

`OSError: Reference at 'refs/heads/master' does already exist, pointing to u'05c3e4762486571918569557d043f5cb59857e06', requested was '23553a1854cebdbe31322d0c1dee5a1aa7b03cf7'`

 which would lead me to believe the local master exists already.

Also, running a `git branch` from within the repo (via git in terminal, outside of the script) shows that I am on master locally.

I tried fetch first just as you mentioned, but still have the same problem.